# Unable to create Scene via Autdoesk forge API

Tags: unity-game-engine, autodesk-forge

I'm following the docs to set up a scene via the forge API here:

http://forgetoolkit.com/#/tutorial?id=step-2-set-up-a-scene

I'm using 3 legged authentication and have tried just about every variation possible when hitting the API and I always get back 400 Bad Request.

[image: Request]

I was told by somebody at Autodesk that `objectId` and `bucketKey` are not needed for 3 legged authentication so I have not included them here (it did not work with them).

I was able to create a scene with the ToolkitService from step #3 here: http://forgetoolkit.com/#/helloworld

I opened the network inspector while it was making the request and even copied all of the parameters from that request to the request that I was making through the API and still no avail. The API hit with ToolkitService is a different endpoint all-together from what is shown in the docs and it only accepts cookies and no authorization header.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This is correct, objectId and bucketKey are used to reference a model in a 2legged context, whereas project_id and version_id reference a model in a 3legged context. Since you work in a 3legged context, did you thought about provisioning your key on your BIM360 account?

Comment: @cyrille I'm not having issues with authentication. We are retrieving an access token for our 3 legged requests and using that on every other endpoint (including this one).